# How to solve React-Router-dom contradicting with context API state

Tags: react-router-dom, react-context

I have the following return function taken form App.js, to keep things clear, the main problem is once I hit a undefined route instead of redirection to 404 it shows a white screen, the redirect is not working at all, even if I use different method like putting 404 component at the bottom, right before switch, it still don't work, I have been experimenting but no luck at all, what is causing this is the state, as you can see in the code I am providing state to certain components if I do set all the providers to the whole app no problem at all but I don't want that, I have 3 states
one global state the wraps four components , and two states wrapping two routes, I even tried to create a context route according to one answer regarding similar problem but still no luck, I thing the state is somehow blocking the flow, for some reason any idea around this ?

```js
return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/signin' exact component={SignIn} />
          <Route path='/restpassword' exact component={RestPassword} />
          <Route path='/signup' exact component={SignUp} />
          <Route path='/404' exact component={NotFound} />
          {/* <ContextRoute exact path='/dashboard' contextComponent={ModalState} component={Dashboard} /> */}
          <GlobalState>
            <Route path='/dashboard' exact component={Dashboard} />
            <FirstState>
              <Route path='/inofrmationA' exact component={inofrmationA} />
            </FirstState>
            <SecondState>
              <Route path='/inofrmationB' exact component={informationB} />
            </SecondState>
            <Route path='/settings' exact component={Settings} />
          </GlobalState>
          // If nothing the trigger redirection to 404 route. 
          <Redirect to='/404' />
        </Switch>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this!!
`<Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I have tried this … Same results … as redirection…